# How to retrieve a particular user data from Firebase and display it in textfields?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

I'M creating an app in android studio using firebase as a backend. I had done with user authentication and storing user entered data in the firebase real-time database.

But now the problem is with the retrieval process of user stored data i.e how to retrieve a particular authenticated user stored data from firebase and display it in text fields?

I tried using Datasnapshot but I'm unable to accomplish my task. Actually, the text fields are displaying as  blank

```
 firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
      //  firebaseStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
     //   DatabaseReference databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
       // databaseReference=firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        //user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
         mdatabaseRef=firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(uid);
         mdatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                   // String firstname = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                  //  fname.setText("firstname :" + firstname);
                    Proceed proceed=postSnapshot.getValue(Proceed.class);
                     String firstname=proceed.getFirstname();
                     String lastname=proceed.getLastname();
                     String phonenumber=proceed.getPhonenumber();
                     String addressc=proceed.getAddressc();
                     String dateofbirth=proceed.getDateofbirth();
                     String gen=proceed.getGen();
                     fname.setText(firstname);
                     lname.setText(lastname);
                     phoneno.setText(phonenumber);
                     address.setText(addressc);
                     dobirth.setText(dateofbirth);
                     gender.setText(gen);
```

The final output, which is I'm expecting is that the displaying of all the user details in a text field which were stored in the firebase

Comment: Hello sir, what is your main problem with your code?

Comment: Please add your database structure and the content of your `Proceed` class and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please add your database structure